# Add fields to event display form

Tags: php, mysql

I am using an open source calendar to display events, I am having a trouble to add extra fields to event display form. Could anyone please indicate where I need to add code so more fields can be displayed. 
Please could anyone kindly help me. 
Many Thanks. 
Here is the code for displaying the events:

```
<?php
require("config.php");
require("./lang/lang." . LANGUAGE_CODE . ".php");
require("functions.php");

$auth   = auth();
$id     = $_GET['id'];

mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT d, m, y FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "mssgs WHERE id=" . $id;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$d          = $row["d"];
$m          = $row["m"];
$y          = $row["y"];
$dateline   = $lang['months'][$m-1] . " $d, $y";
$wday       = date("w", mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y));

writeHeader($m, $y, $dateline, $wday, $auth);

// display selected posting first
writePosting($id, $auth);

// give some space
echo '<img src="images/clear.gif" width="1" height="25" border="0"><br clear="all">';

// query for rest of this day's postings
$sql = "SELECT id, start_time FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "mssgs ";
$sql .= "WHERE y = " . $y . " AND m = " . $m . " AND d = " . $d . " AND id != $id ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY start_time ASC";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo '<span class="display_header">' . $lang['otheritems'] . '</span>';
    echo '<br clear="all"><img src="/images/clear.gif" width="1" height="3" border="0"><br clear="all">';

    // display rest of this day's postings
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        writePosting($row[0], $auth);
        echo '<img src="images/clear.gif" width="1" height="12" border="0"><br clear="all">';
    }
}

echo "</body></html>";


function writeHeader($m, $y, $dateline, $wday, $auth)
{
    global $lang;
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>phpEventCalendar: Event Display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/popwin.css">
<?php if ($auth) { ?>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function deleteConfirm(eid) {
            var msg = "<?php echo $lang['deleteconfirm'] ?>";

            if (confirm(msg)) {
                opener.location = "eventsubmit.php?flag=delete&id=" + eid + "&month=<?php echo $m ?>&year=<?php echo $y ?>";
                window.setTimeout('window.close()', 1000);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php   } ?>
</head>
<body>

<!-- selected date -->
<table cellspadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><span bgcolor="#CCFFCC" class="display_header"><?php echo $dateline ?></span></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC" align="right"><span class="display_header"><?php echo $lang['days'][$wday] ?></span></td>
</tr>
</table>

<img src="images/clear.gif" width="1" height="3" border="0"><br clear="all">
<?php
}

function writePosting($id, $auth)
{
    global $lang;

    mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = "SELECT y, m, d, title, text, start_time, end_time, ";
    $sql .= DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users.uid, fname, lname, ";

    if (TIME_DISPLAY_FORMAT == "12hr") {
        $sql .= "TIME_FORMAT(start_time, '%l:%i%p') AS stime, ";
        $sql .= "TIME_FORMAT(end_time, '%l:%i%p') AS etime ";
    } elseif (TIME_DISPLAY_FORMAT == "24hr") {
        $sql .= "TIME_FORMAT(start_time, '%H:%i') AS stime, ";
        $sql .= "TIME_FORMAT(end_time, '%H:%i') AS etime ";
    } else {
        echo "Bad time display format, check your configuration file.";
    }

    $sql .= "FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "mssgs ";
    $sql .= "LEFT JOIN " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users ";
    $sql .= "ON (" . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "mssgs.uid = " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users.uid) ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id = " . $id;

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $title      = stripslashes($row["title"]);
    $body       = stripslashes(str_replace("\n", "<br />", $row["text"]));
    $postedby   = $lang['postedby'] . ": " . $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'];

    if (!($row["start_time"] == "55:55:55" && $row["end_time"] == "55:55:55")) {
        if ($row["start_time"] == "55:55:55")
            $starttime = "- -";
        else
            $starttime = $row["stime"];

        if ($row["end_time"] == "55:55:55")
            $endtime = "- -";
        else
            $endtime = $row["etime"];

        $timestr = "$starttime - $endtime";
    } else {
        $timestr = "";
    }

    if ($auth == 2 || ($auth != 0 && $_SESSION['authdata']['uid'] == $row['uid'])) {
        $editstr = "<span class=\"display_edit\">";
        $editstr .= "[<a href=\"eventform.php?id=" . $id . "\">edit</a>]&nbsp;";
        $editstr .= "[<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"deleteConfirm(" . $id . ");\">delete</a>]&nbsp;</span>";
    } else {
        $editstr = "";
    }
?>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="300" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
        <tr><td bgcolor="#000000">
            <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="display_title_bg" bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><table bgcolor="#CCFFCC" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tr>
                            <td  bgcolor="#CCFFCC" width="100%"><span class="display_title">&nbsp;<?php echo $title ?></span></td>
                            <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><img src="images/clear.gif" width="20" height="1" border="0"></td>
                            <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC" align="right" nowrap="yes"><span class="display_title"><?php echo $timestr ?>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    </tr></table></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><td  class="display_txt_bg" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                        <tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                            <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><span class="display_txt"><?php echo $body ?></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                            <td  bgcolor="#CCFFCC"align="right"><span class="display_user"><?php echo $postedby ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                            <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><?php echo $editstr ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td></tr>
            </table>
    </td></tr></table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, try to strip out all the extra code. Just let the minor lines as you can to explain the issue. And, if it's possible, put it into http://jsfiddle.net/. You'll get better answers. Good luck!

Comment: in particular, [sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete yet concise.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my understanding writePosting function does most of the job and you need to enhance it to display more info about current event.

I've added a new table row at the end of this code sample to illustrate the idea.

```
                <tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                    <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><span class="display_txt"><?php echo $body ?></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                    <td  bgcolor="#CCFFCC"align="right"><span class="display_user"><?php echo $postedby ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                    <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><?php echo $editstr ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                    <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><?php echo "some extra info" ?></td>
                </tr>
```